# Can't find the reason why my loop doesn't terminate

Tags: c

Good morning.
I have received a task to build a C program, and I've encountered an annoying problem.
I'm trying to scan an unknown length string, which includes only numbers, '-' and spaces, and do something with that string.
The problem is, while scanning it, the program just stops doing anything after finding a minus. It doesn't want to scan any more characters afterwards.
The part where the loop doesn't being terminated:

```
while ((c = getchar()) != '\n' && c != EOF)
    {
        pStr[i++] = (char)c;
        if (c == ' ')
            numCounter++;
        //if i reached maximize size then realloc size
        if (i == current_size)
        {
            current_size = i + len_max;
            pStr = realloc(pStr, current_size);
            if (pStr == NULL)
            {
                printf("Memory allocation failure. \n");
                exit(2);
            }
        }
    }
pStr[i] = '\0';
```

.
.
.

When I was scanning a line that doesn't include minuses, the program did well. The only problem is while scanning a minus.
While debugging, this is the part where my program gets into infinite loop.
Can anyone please point me where's my mistake, so that the program could finally read a minus?

In general, the program gets a line of unknown length of numbers, minuses and spaces. The program would build a polynum. There is a Monom struct, and I want to build an array that would store, in each Monom value, the coefficient (index 0) and the power (index 1).
So my plan was to scan an unknown length string, check where I have numbers, and build a dynamic Monom array that will store the values. Ofcourse I have many more functions that are necessary, like converting a char value to int number, etc.
So far my only problem is the minus part. That could be very helpful if anyone can point me where's my mistake.
Thanks in advance!

Comment: The reason is not in the code you posted. See [How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) then [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/66703531/edit) the question and post the minimal, self-contained code that demonstrates the problem.

Comment: How are you running your program? How does it get the input? Is it typed in from the command line? Redirected into the program?

Comment: @dxiv , @0 0 When I'm debugging, I see that if my string doesn't include minuses, everything works well. The only problem is when there is a minus in the string. No matter where. It just considers the whole string as garbage value, and won't run properly. I've been debugging for like 2 hours, and it always seems that the problem is specific in these lines. The back lines are just some declerations, nothing special...I've declared c as: int c = EOF. Perhaps visual studio counts '-' as EOF?

Comment: @ZvikaCohen You keep describing the code in many words, but that's completely useless. No one can debug the code you are not showing. Instead, you'll need to copy/paste the minimal code required to reproduce the problem.